# Face Recognition in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, face-recognition

I want to create a Chrome browser extension which would be using Face Recognition algorithms to customize personal bookmarks, passwords and themes.

Is there any possibility to use different technologies then JavaScript in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/) (NaCl) to compile C/C++ code into a form that will run safely inside Chrome.  This is feasible as long as the NaCl runtime (provided by the Pepper API) meets your needs.  You will communicate with your NaCl module with Javascript in your application.

Comment: Thnx, what about webcam support?

Comment: You can use [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/chrome) to access the camera from Javascript.  If your question was answered you can mark the answer as useful and/or accept it.

Comment: Is there any way to port OpenCv to NaCl? Could you send me some materials?

Answer (score 0):

I created a Javascript face recognition tutorial here - http://jsfiddle.net/ismaelc/fgq7L/ .(Disclaimer: I work for Mashape).  It's using photobooth.js to capture images, and using Lambda's Face recognition API (https://www.mashape.com/lambda/face-recognition).  I am calling the API like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.mashape.com/recognize",
    type: "POST",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", $("#mashapeKey").val());
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    alert("Received response..");
    var resultObject = JSON.stringify(result);
    alert(resultObject);
});
```

You might also want to check this demo that uses the Skybiometry API (https://www.mashape.com/skybiometry-1/skybiometry-face-detection-and-recognition#!documentation) with webRTC - http://fadomire.futureauth.jit.su/

You can also check out this list of 40+ face recognition APIs, libraries, software - http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis

Answer (score -2):

No, extensions have to be created using HTML and JavaScript.